# 404 Error on files that exist in the proper place on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

This is my first attempt at using GH Pages, and I have a pretty simple blog site created with Vuejs.

I've created my [repo](https://github.com/wonder95/smga), then deployed the built code to a `gh-pages` branch, and the settings are pointed to that branch.

However, I get a `WSOD` when I try to view my [site](https://wonder95.github.io/smga/), and when I look in the console, I get a list of messages that the referenced files can't be found.

When I look in the `/static` directory in the `gh-pages` branch, though, all of the files that it says are missing are actually there where they're supposed to be in relation to index.html.

[image: console errors showing missing files]

What am I missing that keeps the site from showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the requests, you would find out requesting

https://wonder95.github.io/static/css/app.da01b7b80b6795e91d3ceace476633af.css

This has missed the `/smga/` part, and is not what published in your git pages. As the correct link should be
    https://wonder95.github.io/smga/static/css/app.da01b7b80b6795e91d3ceace476633af.css